# Convert HTML output to String

Tags: html, string

I want to convert HTML output (what a person can see on browser) to String (it may be a set of Strings actually)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="vk_c _cy obcontainer card-section">
    <div class="_frf"><select class="_nif _Ohf ik4llLYIcrKE-trqxvH0pmCk" jsaction="change:r.3r2U78ZXCIY"
                              data-rtid="ik4llLYIcrKE" jsl="$x 1;" data-ved="0ahUKEwie8vbnkLXRAhWDbxQKHa5dBxUQ6WoIGzAA">
        <option value="Area">Area</option>
        <option value="Data Transfer Rate">Data Transfer Rate</option>
        <option value="Digital Storage">Digital Storage</option>
        <option value="Energy">Energy</option>
        <option value="Frequency">Frequency</option>
        <option value="Fuel Economy">Fuel Economy</option>
        <option value="Length">Length</option>
        <option value="Mass">Mass</option>
        <option value="Plane Angle">Plane Angle</option>
        <option value="Pressure">Pressure</option>
        <option value="Speed">Speed</option>
        <option value="Temperature">Temperature</option>
        <option value="Time">Time</option>
        <option selected="1" value="Volume">Volume</option>
    </select></div>
    <div class="_cif" id="_Aif"><input class="_eif ik4llLYIcrKE-TAgAjI3bJNo" value="1"
                                       jsaction="change:r.EQNHKrw0qdA;keyup:r.EQNHKrw0qdA;r.JnbD_-w_xe0"
                                       data-rtid="ik4llLYIcrKE" jsl="$x 2;"
                                       data-ved="0ahUKEwie8vbnkLXRAhWDbxQKHa5dBxUQ5WoIHDAA"> <select
            class="_dif _Ohf ik4llLYIcrKE-y69YkR-bRoA" id="_Bif" jsaction="change:r.tDOMoafrm4E"
            data-rtid="ik4llLYIcrKE" jsl="$x 3;" data-ved="0ahUKEwie8vbnkLXRAhWDbxQKHa5dBxUQ5moIHTAA">
        <option text="US liquid gallon">US liquid gallon</option>
        <option text="US liquid quart">US liquid quart</option>
        <option text="US liquid pint">US liquid pint</option>
        <option text="US legal cup">US legal cup</option>
        <option text="US fluid ounce">US fluid ounce</option>
        <option selected="1" text="US tablespoon">US tablespoon</option>
        <option text="US teaspoon">US teaspoon</option>
        <option text="Cubic metre">Cubic metre</option>
        <option text="Litre">Litre</option>
        <option text="Millilitre">Millilitre</option>
        <option text="Imperial gallon">Imperial gallon</option>
        <option text="Imperial quart">Imperial quart</option>
        <option text="Imperial pint">Imperial pint</option>
        <option text="Imperial cup">Imperial cup</option>
        <option text="Imperial fluid ounce">Imperial fluid ounce</option>
        <option text="Imperial tablespoon">Imperial tablespoon</option>
        <option text="Imperial teaspoon">Imperial teaspoon</option>
        <option text="Cubic foot">Cubic foot</option>
        <option text="Cubic inch">Cubic inch</option>
    </select></div>
    <div class="_oif">=</div>
    <div class="_cif" id="_Cif"><input class="_eif ik4llLYIcrKE-7Ob2ZtRDv2s" value="3"
                                       jsaction="change:r.Y8jfekOjBAk;keyup:r.Y8jfekOjBAk;r.GsMrmfckh-M"
                                       data-rtid="ik4llLYIcrKE" jsl="$x 4;"
                                       data-ved="0ahUKEwie8vbnkLXRAhWDbxQKHa5dBxUQ52oIHjAA"> <select
            class="_dif _Ohf ik4llLYIcrKE-EXIkszwxM2g" jsaction="change:r.xd0JMVj7UXs" data-rtid="ik4llLYIcrKE"
            jsl="$x 5;" data-ved="0ahUKEwie8vbnkLXRAhWDbxQKHa5dBxUQ6GoIHzAA">
        <option text="US liquid gallon">US liquid gallon</option>
        <option text="US liquid quart">US liquid quart</option>
        <option text="US liquid pint">US liquid pint</option>
        <option text="US legal cup">US legal cup</option>
        <option text="US fluid ounce">US fluid ounce</option>
        <option text="US tablespoon">US tablespoon</option>
        <option selected="1" text="US teaspoon">US teaspoon</option>
        <option text="Cubic metre">Cubic metre</option>
        <option text="Litre">Litre</option>
        <option text="Millilitre">Millilitre</option>
        <option text="Imperial gallon">Imperial gallon</option>
        <option text="Imperial quart">Imperial quart</option>
        <option text="Imperial pint">Imperial pint</option>
        <option text="Imperial cup">Imperial cup</option>
        <option text="Imperial fluid ounce">Imperial fluid ounce</option>
        <option text="Imperial tablespoon">Imperial tablespoon</option>
        <option text="Imperial teaspoon">Imperial teaspoon</option>
        <option text="Cubic foot">Cubic foot</option>
        <option text="Cubic inch">Cubic inch</option>
    </select></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Despite there is so many code, when you run the snippet You actually see texts as "Volume" "1" "US Tablespoon" "=" "3" "US Teaspoon"

I search for an algorithm to only return these texts from a HTML code like that, is it possible?

Comment: You need to use JavaScript

Comment: Can you please elaborate the way please,
if you mention parsing it and in for loop getting .text for text elements and getting text of combobox by .getSelectedIndex

there is possibility that a html element I didn't see before might come

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if you use something like Python [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) you could simply load the document into it and output the text.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """
    your HTML string
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
print(soup.get_text())
```

Comment: I tried version BeautifulSoup4 in python 3.4 , I also tried using 'html.parser' instead of 'lxml' but same output, is there anything I am missing?

Output is going like
"AreaData Transfer RateDigital StorageEnergyFrequencyFuel EconomyLengthMassPlane AnglePressureSpeedTemperatureTimeVolume      US liquid gallonUS liquid quartUS liquid pintUS legal cupUS..."